# How to handle Null Values in simple dynamic SQL query

Tags: mysql, ado, delphi-2010

I want to give my end user the option of querying a MySQL database dynamically.  I have provided two textboxes for them to enter their search criteria and following this, click on a button to run query. The first textbox allows them to enter an integer for searching the LoanID field. The second textbox allows them to enter an integer for searching the BookID field. The query works fine when BOTH criteria have been entered, however, if the end user only wants to search with, say, a BookID i get no results in the query.  Is there a way i can handle non-entries (nulls) so that the query will work even with one criteria entered?

I am using ADOquery, with MySQL DB, where the data types for both the LoanID and BookID fields is integer. 
The table is a typical Library Database Loan Table showing [LoanID], [LoanDate], [BorrowerID],[BookID]. Here is the SQL so far...following the advice given.

```
adoquery1.SQL.Clear;
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('SELECT LoanID, LoanDate, BorrowerSurname,Loan.BookID, BookTitle   FROM Loan,Book,Borrower' );
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('WHERE Borrower.BorrowerID = Loan.BorrowerID AND');
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('Loan.BookID = Book.BookID AND');
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('LoanID = :LoanID OR :loanID IS NULL AND ');
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('Loan.BookID = :BookID OR :BookID IS NULL');
  adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('LoanID').Value:= edit1.Text;
  adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('BookID').Value:= edit2.Text;
  adoquery1.open;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `1 = 1` as your first condition and construct the query by adding additional conditions only if they are filled in.

This is a standard practice, in pseudocode (PHP actually). :

```
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
$qry .= ' WHERE 1 = 1';
if ($loanID) {
  $qry .= ' AND loanID = :loanID';
}
if ($bookID) {
  $qry .= ' AND bookID = :bookID';
}
$sth = $dbh->prepare($qry);
if ($loanID) {
  $sth.bindParam(':loanID', $loanID);
}
if ($bookID) {
  $sth.bindParam(':bookID', $bookID);
}
$sth->execute();
```

Alternatively, you can do this in SQL, but it's not as efficient. Pass in `NULL`s as parameters in this case:

```
$qry = 'SELECT * from table1';
$qry .= ' WHERE (loanID = :loanID OR :loanID IS NULL)';
$qry .= ' AND (bookID = :bookID OR :bookID IS NULL)';
```

Comment: I tried to alter SQL like you recommended - see original post edit. Getting message: " Parameter Object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or Incomplete information was provided".

Comment: Do you need spaces after the ANDs and before WHERE? I don't know how your SQL.Add() function works. Anyway, you should be able to work out the details from my sample.